# Moving from SQLite to Core Data

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm moving my SQLite database over to Core Data. My database table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops (id integer primary key autoincrement, type text, lat real, lon real, stop_id integer unique, stop_code integer, title text, subtitle text, url text, lastupdate text
```

My Entity looks like this:

[image]

I'm not worries about moving the data over, it's really just a local cache that gets updated from time to time. If its empty, it will just repopulate.

My issue is I have a SQLite custom function:

```
static void distanceFunc(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv)
{
    // check that we have four arguments (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
    assert(argc == 4);
    // check that all four arguments are non-null
    if (sqlite3_value_type(argv[0]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[1]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[2]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[3]) == SQLITE_NULL) {
        sqlite3_result_null(context);
        return;
    }
    // get the four argument values
    double lat1 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[0]);
    double lon1 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[1]);
    double lat2 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[2]);
    double lon2 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[3]);
    // convert lat1 and lat2 into radians now, to avoid doing it twice below
    double lat1rad = DEG2RAD(lat1);
    double lat2rad = DEG2RAD(lat2);
    // apply the spherical law of cosines to our latitudes and longitudes, and set the result appropriately
    // 6378.1 is the approximate radius of the earth in kilometres
    sqlite3_result_double(context, acos(sin(lat1rad) * sin(lat2rad) + cos(lat1rad) * cos(lat2rad) * cos(DEG2RAD(lon2) - DEG2RAD(lon1))) * 6378.1);
}
```

The function given a 2 latitudes and 2 longitudes would return the distance. This would let me do something like:

```
SELECT *, distance(lat, lon, %f, %f) as dist FROM stops WHERE dist < 1 ORDER BY dist
```

Now, I've got all my data in Core Data, but no idea how to do something like the SQL above with a `NSFetchRequest`. So how would I go about fetching entities in this manner?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I perform a calculated query using CoreData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409912/how-do-i-perform-a-calculated-query-using-coredata)

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra - The issue is the question isn't the same as mine. The SQL there isn't looking at a calculated field in the WHERE clause, it's returning a calculated field as part of the results. So the NSPredicate is simple and then sorted after the fact.

Comment: It is the same because you **can't** calculate in the query.  You must do a bounding box and then calculate against the objects returned inside the bounding box.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra - If thats true, Core Data is a lot less useful than it's made out to be. Ah well, back to SQLite I guess.

Comment: Core Data is very useful but **it is not a database**. It is an object graph (aka your model) that can persist to disk and one of the formats of that persistence can be SQLite.  Core Data is designed to work with objects in memory not rows in a SQLite file.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra - Right, but requesting a set of object that meet a certain criteria seems an important thing to have.